# Bluetooth PC cannot pair with Bluetooth Device. Why?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, keyboard, bluetooth

I bought a pretty little Bluetooth Keyboard the other day.

Name: OfficeOne Bluetooth Keyboard
Model: PJT-DKB283

Its packaging states that it can connect to Windows XP, Vista, 7 and 8 - *and* mac.

The instructions in the instruction manual only show you how to connect it to an iPad. But I have successfully connected/paired it [to]with a Windows Phone HTC 8S and my Samsung Galaxy S3 LTE smartphone. And it works on the phones.

However this is not my intended use. I bought it so I could connect it to my computer. I am running Windows 7 and Windows 8. I mainly use Windows 8 and want to use it only on Windows 8. But Windows 8 (and 8.1), and 7, and also Linux (elementary OS) do *not* detect this keyboard.

My computer has built-in Bluetooth and other devices used to connect to it just fine (I rarely use Bluetooth on my PC).

After realising this keyboard won't connect to my computer, I tried pairing my Windows Phone with Windows 8. But keep getting "No device found" message. And my phones aren't picking up my computer as a Bluetooth device either.

**How do I pair/connect my Bluetooth keyboard with Windows 8 and/or 8.1?**

Please don't suggest any online tutorials unless you know for sure they actually work. I've already tried over 30 tutorials in the last 3 days and I'm not going to waste anymore time on them because it's basically the same approach with different wording.

Some more details:

When I open up Device manager, Bluetooth is not listed anywhere.

When I open up Task Manager, Bluetooth service is "running".

Comment: Have you contacted OfficeOne support?

Comment: @DaveM that would seem like the next logical step. But I have a feeling that the problem is Windows-related and _not_ the fault of OfficeOne; which is why I mentioned that the Keyboard does actually work with everything else.

Comment: Does this keyboard come with a Bluetooth reciever?  A product website might be helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks. I would havelinked to a product website but I can't even find it. It's not listed on their manual or packaging and a Google search doesn't reveal anything other than different companies with the same name but none of them have any text related to this keyboard. Also no phone numbers I can find either. No, it did not come with a receiver. Which suprised me. But then again, if it needs a receiver then why does it work flawlessly with my phones? Also, the packaging on the outside does not indicate a receiver is included

Comment: I called the store where I bought it from and they "don't have the number for OfficeOne". I then looked at the packaging again, and it says "OfficeOne is a trademark of Kmart Australia" (Kmart is where I bought the KB from.) So I went to Kmart's site, searched all over it, looked for keyboards and office one and nothing at all.

Comment: @Tommy - What about the receiver?  If it didn't come with one, and your computer does not have Bluetoother capabilities, then your not going to be able to get it working.

Comment: @Ramhound as stated in my question, my computer does have Bluetooth capabilities. From my question: "My computer has built-in Bluetooth and other devices used to connect to it just fine (I rarely use Bluetooth on my PC)." :)

Comment: @Tommy - I really do aplogize, I glazed over that fact, I focus on certain elements of a problem ( because I have found those elements are the most common places people make mistakes ).  Do you know anything about the about blluetooth capabilties of your pc?  If the device is not listed, that would seem to indicate, the device isn't installed.

Comment: @Ramhound no need to apologize :) Happens to all of us. I have been going over this in my head all day and night. I don't know how else to try and fix this when nothing related to bluetooth appears on my computer anymore. Just last month (the last time I used bluetooth) was when I was testing a windows 8 sample bluetooth app in C# and it was working. I even remember clicking the little blue bluetooth icon in the tray and doing something in there, but now there appears to be no evidence of bluetooth. I have even double checked the manufacturer website to make sure my computer does [1 of 2]

Comment: [2 of 2] have bluetooth (even though i already know - it's just making me think i'm crazy cause i just can't find any evidence of it on my machine). The manufacturer website (HP) says my exact model PC does infact have bluetooth. I don't know how to install bluetooth device cause I don't know where to get it. I've searched online and all I could find was some Broadcom software that just hangs on "pair a device". (Sorry if this sounds a bit all over the place but I haven't slept for 26 hours :-)